# Batch file not calling other batch files

Tags: batch-file

I have a set of three automatically generated batch files, summed up below

### `arbitrary.bat`

```
@ECHO OFF
set APPDATA=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Minecrafts\1.9p5\
set T1=ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
set T2=³ÍÍÍ 1.9p5 ÍÍÍ³
set T3=ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
masterControl
```

### `masterControl.bat`

```
varInit
[main program logic...]
```

### `varInit.bat`

```
set U=valueOfU
set P=valueOfP
set S=valueOfS
pause
```

The idea is that `arbitrary.bat` is run and the other two are called, as well. However, the program stops right after `masterControl` runs its first line (all lines in `varInit` are run successfully). **Why doesn't this program run past the first line of `masterControl`?

Comment: I don't use windows, but I'd bet `pause` waits for user input. Did you hit `enter` after it got there?

Comment: yes -_- I put `pause` there for debugging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the command `CALL` to call each batch file from another i.e. `CALL masterControl.bat`

Comment: then why does `masterControl.bat` run its first line?

Comment: Every subsequent batch file execution (without using the call command) will abort the execution of the caller. Calling varInit from masterControl aborts the execution of masterControl so masterControl won't continue after varInit completes.

Comment: If a Batch file execute another one with no `call` command, the result is equivalent to a "goto to another file": when the second Batch file ends the whole execution ends. I call _Overlay_ a Batch file executed this way (instead of _Subroutine_ that returns when end).